# Using Googlemail with Outlook and also have the same 'folderstructure'

Tags: google-chrome, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail

I like using the normal googlemail-site or app on the android-phone that Google automatically filters the Incoming mails very well and put them in different folders so my Inbox is very 'clean'.

However, when importing the googlemail-adress in outllok for example I only have 'one big' Inbox with huge amount of mails 80% spam or mails which are not important for me.

Is it somehow possible to let Outlook use the prefiltered and categorized structure from Google?

Comment: How did you add the google account to outlook?

Comment: >>I like using the normal googlemail-site or app on the android-phone that Google automatically filters the Incoming mails very well and put them in different folders so my Inbox is very 'clean'.<< How did you/Gmail do this? Could you share a screenshot on this?